# MUI DatePicker not working with react-intl

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, react-intl

I have a table where I am modifying the date format based on the locale using this react-intl library.

```
const intl = useIntl();
<p>
  {intl.formatDate(//DATE)}
</p>
```

Now i have a date picker using MUI date picker:

```
   <LocalizationProvider
          dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
          adapterLocale={(locales as Record<string, Locale>)[intl.locale]}
        >
          <DatePicker
            value={filterValue?.values?.[0] ?? null}
            onChange={handleDateChange}
            slots={{
              toolbar: DatePickerToolbar,
            }}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
```

When i select locale to be "it" it is working fine but when I am selecting "it-IT" the table is showing in **DD/MM/YY** format but the datepicker is showing in **MM/DD/YY** format. How to make both picker and table working on the same format ??